# Can't mock a factory method that calls another factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, factory

I have a factory like this

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('Utils', function () {
   function one() {
   }

   function two() {
     one();
   }

   return {
     one: one,
     two: two
 });
});
```

In a jasmine spec I attempt to do something like this:

```
it('should verify', inject(function(Utils) {
  spyOn(Utils, 'one');
  Utils.two();
  expect(Utils.one).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

However I get an error saying the spy was never called.  I guess it some sort of reference issue.  Any idea why I can't spyOn a factory function that is called from another function in the same factory?

Answer (score 1):

You need to track all calls via [`callThrough()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E):

```
spyOn(Utils, 'one').and.callThrough();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by tweaking the factory to this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('Utils', function () {
var utils = {};

function one() {
}

function two() {
 utils.one();
}

utils = {
 one: one,
 two: two
}

return utils;
});
```